# In MPI how to communicate a part of a "shared" array to all other ranks?

Tags: mpi, broadcast

I have an MPI program with some array of data. Every rank needs all the array to do its work, but will only work on a patch of the array. After a calculation step I need every rank to communicate its computed piece of the array to all other ranks.

**How do I achieve this efficiently?**

In pseudo code I would do something like this as a first approach:

```
if rank == 0: // only master rank
  initialise_data()
end if

MPI_Bcast(all_data,0) // from master to every rank

compute which part of the data to work on

for ( several steps ): // each rank
  execute_computation(part_of_data)

  for ( each rank ):
    MPI_Bcast(part_of_data, rank_number) // from every rank to every rank
  end for
end for
```

The disadvantage is that there is as many broadcasts, i.e. barriers as there is ranks. So how would I replace the MPI_Bcasts ?

**edit:** I just might have found a hint... Is it MPI_Allgather I am looking for?

Comment: What you are looking for is `MPI_Allgather` (or `MPI_Allgatherv` if chunks are of varying size) in in-place mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for `MPI_Allgather`. Note that `recvcount` is not the length of the whole recieve buffer, but the amount of data should be recieved from one process. Analogically, in `MPI_Allgatherv` `recvcount[i]` is the amount of data you want to recieve from i-th process. Moreover, `recvcount` should be equal (not less) to the respective `sendcount`. I tested it on my implemetation (OpenMPI), and if I tried to recieve less elements that were sent, I got `MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE` error.

Also in some rare cases I used `MPI_Allreduce` for that puprose. For example if we have the following arrays:

```
process0: AA0000
process1: 0000BB
process2: 00CC00
```

then we can do Allreduce with `MPI_SUM` operation and get `AACCBB` in all processes. Obviously, the same trick can be done with ones instead of zeros and `MPI_PROD` instead of `MPI_SUM`.

Comment: Ok... One more question: Is recvcount always the same as sendcount? And a comment: I can't use Allreduce because in the other fields there is the "old" data. Of course I could set is to 0...

Comment: @steffen I updated the answer. Yes, it always should be the same, or you get the error. For now, I tested it on MPICH as well, and got the same error. If the patches of your array have different sizes in different process, use allgatherv, but keep `recvcount[i]` equal to `sendcount` of i-th process. Using allreduce for this purpose is very uncommon and it will work slower than allgather in most cases. Surely you shouldn't use it if there is "old" data in the buffer.

Comment: The number of primitive data items sent should match the number of primitive data items received, not the values of `sendcount` and `recvcount`. For example, one might send 100 `MPI_INT` elements and receive 1 element of a user-defined vector type that consists of 100 `MPI_INT` elements.